# Calling labview dll from asp.net not working all the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, invoke, labview

I am using a `LABVIEW dll` for saving file content in the MySQL database 
The code I am using is

```
var dll = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(Server.MapPath("~/Bin/File_Import.dll"));
var dllClass = dll.GetType("File_Import.LabVIEWExports");
var method = dllClass.GetMethod("File_Import");
if (method.Name != string.Empty)
{
    var result1 = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { paths, ipAddress, parameterIDs, CurrentSchema.SchemaName, false, serverPath });
    uint result = (uint)result1;

    if (result != 0)
    {
        Logger.WriteMessageToLog("File Path: " + paths + " IPAddress" + ipAddress + " File ID" + parameterIDs + " Schema" + CurrentSchema.SchemaName + " Server Path" + serverPath);
    }
}
```

**Most weird thing that it is not working all the time, sometime a get this error**

> Error Message
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Exception Sourcemscorlib
>   Exception Stack   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at TestEditor.SaveCasePermamently()
>   Inner Exception MessageObject reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Inner Exception SourceFile_Import
>   Inner exception Stack   at File_Import.LabVIEWExports.File_Import(String file_Path, String iP_Addr, String fileID, String database, Boolean stopTagNotFound, String log_Path)

I am wondering what can be reason it is working sometime and not working sometime

Can anyone help here?

Thanks a lot

Monika

Comment: LabVIEW is an interactive application.  Does it support being called from IIS (where your ASP.NET application is likely running).  Most interactive applications behave badly when called form services.  For example, Office apps come with this warning: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office.  If you gin up an Office object model in a web app, it works sometimes, and fails sometimes (usually at the worst time).  Sometimes, it just hangs your application

Comment: @Flydog57 LabVIEW is a development environment. Applications and libraries that are built from LabVIEW don't need to be "interactive". I have used LabVIEW to write a data acquisition library (DLL) that my customer drives through an IIS service -- the client GUI runs on a different laptop than the data acquisition PC, but both machines are on the same network. The library itself has no GUI; it simply reacts to function calls like `startAcquisition()` and `stopAcquisition()`. The library has been in active use for 3 years now.

Comment: Sorry, the last time I looked at LabVIEW was in the 90s (yeah, I'm old).  The inner exception indicates that it likely has nothing to do with the Reflection call, that it's one of the arguments in the call to: `File_Import.LabVIEWExports.File_Import(String file_Path, String iP_Addr, String fileID, String database, Boolean stopTagNotFound, String log_Path)`.  It's not the Boolean, so it's one of those strings.  Consider putting a log statement in _before_ the Invoke, with the values protected against null (something like `paths??"[NULL]"`)

Comment: Yes all null protection is there , even logging parameters passed while calling dll , no parameter with null going